# issue while setting time for alarm Manager

Tags: android

hey guys am facing a weird problem when am setting the time for my alarm manager for my notification its not giving me notification this is what am tying :

```
        notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    notification.setAutoCancel(true);

    counter = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent("android.media.action.DISPLAY_NOTIFICATION");
    notificationIntent.addCategory("android.intent.category.DEFAULT");

    PendingIntent broadcast = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 5000, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();



    cal.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 22);
    cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 43);
    cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    cal.add(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);


    // cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 20);

    alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), broadcast);
```

but when am setting my alarm while using only `cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 20)` its giving me the notification (working fine) so any one can tell me why its not working when am using Hours, minutes and why its working only when i use `Seconds` only ??/ any help will be much appreciated , thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Indra notes in his answer, you are incorrectly using `cal.getTimeInMillis()` both for the alarm trigger time **and** the interval.  That value is not a valid interval.  Presumably, you want the alarm to fire every hour, day, or some other reasonable interval. I'm guessing that because the interval you are requesting is a huge value, and the alarm you are requesting is inexact, you never see it fire even once because of this behavior explained in the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setInexactRepeating(int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)): "Your alarm's first trigger will not be before the requested time, but it might not occur for almost a full interval after that time". In this case "full interval" is roughly 46 years.

Comment: hey @qbix thanks for your  response :) ,  can you please take a look on my updated question cause am still having the same problem ,and not getting any notification when am setting time ( cal.add.HOUR_OF_DAY, 22) by doing this , its only giving me notification when am using  ( cal.add.SECOND, 22)

Comment: @remyboys: I experimented with `Calendar.add()` and didn't see anything wrong with the way you are creating a time for 22 hours, 43 minutes in the future.  How are you confirming that you are not getting an alarm at that time without waiting 22+ hours?

Comment: is it going to give me the alarm after 22 hour or the 22 hour stands for time ? like it will going to give it on 10o clock ?

Comment: am assuming that adding hours means setting the time according to our clock like if i set it for 22 hours 43 minutes and the current time is 10:41 pm so i thought it'll give me the alarm in next 2 minutes , am i wrong here ???

Comment: Yes, that's the confusion.  `Calendar.getInstance()` initializes the calendar object to the current time.  The `add` operations add the specified number of hours, minutes, seconds to the current time. In this case, the alarm will first fire 22 hours, 43 minutes in the future, not at wall time 22:43.  Explained in the overview of the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html).  To get a specific wall time, use the `set` methods.

Comment: my bad , now working fine thanks man for clearing my doubt :)

Comment: Plus 1 for 46 years :)

Answer (score 2):

Please find the method and its params below

```
   setInexactRepeating (int type, long triggerAtMillis, long intervalMillis, PendingIntent operation)
```

if you want to repeat the alarm everyday at 22:43:00 then call like this

```
alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
        AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, alarmIntent);
```

if you want to repeat the alarm every 15 mins  then call like this

```
alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
        AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES, alarmIntent);
```

Comment: thanks for responding dude but my problem is not repeating it my problem is that am not able to set the time for `alarmManager` i can only set the `Second` if i add hours or minutes or date it won't work , its working  only when am using `seconds` only